# classes .m and .h not updated

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

kinda awkward asking this. But I cant seem to find the solution, because I dont know how/what to search in google. It goes something like this. In my project folder, whenever I click my `Project.xcodeproj` the latest code I have edited there was right or what I meant is when opened in `XCODE` it is updated.

**Problem:**

For example, when I try to unzip my latest project from the latest zipped project( for back-up purposes ) when I open the folder( back up ) then click for example `View1Controller.m` the codes in it arent updated the way they are in the `XCODE` though if I click the `xcodeproj` part. It is updated in the `XCODE`.

Hope someone could help me with this, and explain some good ways/solution for my prob. Thanks.

Comment: Ctrl+click on your file in Xcode and choose "Show in Finder". This will show your file in Finder and let you check where the file is. I think you saved your file in wrong place.

Comment: I think it is all under my folder. Kinda weird though. Ill try to check again tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are zipping old projects and saving them to avoid using git - I'm no git lover but for sure its a better solution.

The problem with trying to use Xcode to view old and new projects at the same time is (IMHO) is that Xcode seems to get confused about what file is in what project - if you have a new one and old one open.

- open the old file in TextEdit, it should be exactly what you think it should be
- in Xcode, have the current project open, look at some files. close the project, and open the older project. look at the files, they should be correct [if they are not, close and reopen Xcode between project openings, but I suspect this is not necessary]
- if you really need to see the files from the old project while viewing the new ones, then in the Finder rename the file - put a "O" prefix on the file, then open that file (with the modified name) in Xcode

My experience is dated on this issue to older releases, but I do strongly recall having this kind of problem in the past.

Comment: I don't understand the question - if you mean the above, well, those are options - there may be others. In the past, I had problems trying to open a project, and an older version of it. Xcode uses internal tag IDs for the resources in a project, and when you have two of the same project open these IDs are of course duplicated. That said, I don't know exactly how Xcode 4 does it. Since you are experiencing oddities, I'm trying to give you workarounds on how you might do what you want to do.